# Retweeting with ColdFusion and Twitter4j

Tags: coldfusion, twitter, twitter4j

I'm trying to update the status of a user and then immediately retweet it. I can't figure out how to get the ID of the status I just submitted though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing a

```
twitter.updateStatus("Some String");
```

If so, this returns a [Status](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html), which has a getId() method

```
myStatus = twitter.updateStatus("Some String");
myId = myStatus.getId();
```

If not, please post your code.